# My Facebook Feed Gaming no longer working

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I was testing Facebook's feed gaming feature with a dummy flash file, and it was working great a couple of weeks ago.  I would click the link and the flash file would open up right in the timeline.  However now when I click the link it opens the URL in a new browser.  I haven't changed anything.  I've tried to re-create the post with no luck.  I've created a new Facebook app, added source/picture tags to the open graph object, create new URL, using http and https in the Open Graph object, and made sure my SSL is up to date.  I've research to see if any changes have been made to Feed Gaming however I cannot find anything online or in news articles.  Here is the link to my test post.  It's the only post on the page.

https://www.facebook.com/DenverDailyDeal

Here is my Open Graph object:

```
<html lang="en" xmlns:fb="https://www.facebook.com/2008/fbml">
<head prefix="og: http://ogp.me/ns fb: http://ogp.me/ns/fb">   
   <meta property="fb:app_id"       content="XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX" />
   <meta property="og:type"         content="game" />
   <meta property="og:url"          content="https://XXXXXXXXX.com/facebook/" />
   <meta property="og:title"        content="The Title" />
   <meta property="og:description"  content="The description" />
   <meta property="og:image"        content="https://XXXXXXXXX.com/facebook/200.png" />
   <meta property="og:video"        content="https://XXXXXXXXX.com/facebook/contact.swf" />
   <meta property="og:video:width"  content="398" />
   <meta property="og:video:height" content="398" />
   <meta property="og:video:type"   content="application/x-shockwave-flash" />
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.  Thanks and have a great one.

Comment: Does the [debugger](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug) report that everything is working correctly?

Comment: Yes everything does look okay in the debugger:

Comment: It also shows:

Type of Share
Video
status Video embedding on Facebook enabled

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

I am also experiencing this problem.

I've noticed that this is an intermittent issue as it works for some people but not others. Whenever I access the post, it launches in a new window but for some of my colleagues it works fine i.e. in-feed.

I've also noticed that the problem exists even if you share a YouTube video, so it doesn't seem like we are doing anything wrong here, just a bug with Facebook.

@user2997979: Have you had any luck since?